# Onclick prepend link to image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code below that consist of a HTML tab with a image inside of it. What i'm currently trying accomplish is to create a onclick function for when i click the capture button it will `prepend` a link infront of my image src to make it something like this

`<img src="https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/4/49/Ash_Pikachu.png/250px-Ash_Pikachu.png" width="300" height="300" >`

And it will remove the link after the image is downloaded what i have done below is that i try to prepend a text to my link but it doesn't seem to work. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```js
function sendData() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById('capture'), {
    allowTaint: false,
    useCORS: true
  }).then(function(canvas) {
    var openList = $('[data-target="#openly"]');
    $('#testaroni').prepend('src', 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + openList.attr('src'));
    $('#test').attr('href', canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    $('#test').attr('download', 'Test.png');
    $('#test')[0].click();
  });
}


function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-bottom: 8px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 25px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  background-color: white;
}

.jobs-panel {
  display: table;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  background-color: #b7bcbe;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.tabwidth {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>

  </style>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="capture">
    <div class="jobs-panel">

      <div class="tabwidth">
        <div class="tab">
          <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
        </div>

        <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
          <img id="testaroni" data-target="#openly"  src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/4/49/Ash_Pikachu.png/250px-Ash_Pikachu.png" width="300" height="300">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="sendData()" ;>Capture!</button>
  <a id="test" href="#"></a>
</body>

</html>

<script>
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: @Mr.Alien isit wrong to do it this way?

Comment: @Tommy depends on who you ask.

Comment: You can use both simultaneously, but depends on your approach whether the code will work or not.

Comment: Does anyone know how to accomplish the above problem?